# How to pass option value and label created with ng-repeat triggered by ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating options with an ng-repeat and on ng-change I would like to call a controller function and pass the option value and label. I have tried to also create the options using ng-options but have fallen into a rat hole of ng-repeat filters that did not help.

I can pass the ng-model to the function and that gets me the value, but not both the value and label.

Here is the code I have that represents what I'd like do but is obviously not functional because the ng-change function call is outside the ng-repeat.

```
diskSizes = [ 
 {
   "label": "100GB",
   "value": 100
 },
 {
   "label": "250GB",
   "value": 250
 },
 {
   "label": "500GB",
   "value": 500
 },
 {
   "label": "1TB",
   "value": 1000
 },
 {
   "label": "1.5TB",
   "value": 1500
 }
]
```

HTML

```
<td > 
    <select ng-model="disk_size" ng-change="saveData(value,label)">
           <option ng-repeat="item in diskSizes" value={{item.value}}>{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically with angularJS, the HTML just reflects the data structure, and it's the data structure where you probably should grab the label value.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.diskSizes = [{
        "label": "100GB",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "label": "250GB",
        "value": 250
      },
      {
        "label": "500GB",
        "value": 500
      },
      {
        "label": "1TB",
        "value": 1000
      },
      {
        "label": "1.5TB",
        "value": 1500
      }
    ]

    $scope.saveData = function() {
      let val = $scope.disk_size;
      let lab = $scope.diskSizes.filter(f => f.value == val)[0].label;
      console.log(lab, val)
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="disk_size" ng-change="saveData()">
    <option ng-repeat="item in diskSizes" value={{item.value}}>{{item.label}}</option>
  </select>


</div>
```